# HTML CSS text align

Tags: html, css, text-align

attached is an image. 
[image]

I am trying to get the text format as shown at the right-most end. i.e. within the height of the thumbnail (36px) name, time, date have to be shown vertically aligned. I am having problem showing the text vertically aligned. Here's my code -

```
<div id="sresults" style="position:absolute;top:120px; left:36%;">
    <div id="0" style="width:500px;padding:5px;cursor:pointer;clear:both;">
        <div id="content0" style="float:left; font-size:13px;">"Hey dude how are you doing?"</div>
        <div id="meta0" style="float:right;">
           <img src="http://www.mnducksvolunteer.org/_/rsrc/1262377955090/services/Google-Contacts-32.png" width="36px" title='Google Contacts'></img>
           <img src="http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/hs455.snc4/49881_1146922913_477096_q.jpg" width="36" title="peter"></img>
           <div id='name' style="float:right; font-size:11px">Peter</div>
           <div id='time' style="float:right;font-size:11px;">19:23</div>
           <div id='date' style="float:right;font-size:11px;">23 Dec'10</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

To be accurate, I want the div ids 'name', 'time', 'date' to be aligned like in the image. how?

Also note that the div with id="0" is one of the results, there'll be 10 such in a page all under `<div id="sresults">`

Comment: just in case, ids and classes must start with letter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you want: http://www.bravegnuworld.com/rjune/test.html

Notice encapsulating the name, etc in a div that is floated right? You have three divs(block elements, they'll automatically stack). Put those inside another div, and you now have a block element with three stacked blocks inside it. You can either use "float:right" or "display:inline-block" to make the div display on the same level. as the rest of the line.

```
<div id="sresults" style="position:absolute;top:120px; left:36%; background:yellow">
  <div id="0" style="width:500px;padding:5px;cursor:pointer;clear:both; background:red">
    <div id="content0" style="float:left; font-size:13px; background:blue">"Hey dude how are you doing?"</div>
    <div id="meta0" style="float:right; background:green">
     <img src="http://www.mnducksvolunteer.org/_/rsrc/1262377955090/services/Google-Contacts-32.png" width="36px" title='Google Contacts'></img>
     <img src="http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/hs455.snc4/49881_1146922913_477096_q.jpg" width="36" title="peter"></img>
      <div style="float:right">
        <div id='name' style="font-size:11px">Peter</div>
        <div id='time' style="font-size:11px;">19:23</div>
        <div id='date' style="font-size:11px;">23 Dec'10</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `table` instead of `div` it's seems more logical to me:

```
<div id="sresults" style="position:absolute;top:120px; left:36%;">
    <div id="0" style="width:500px;padding:5px;cursor:pointer;clear:both;">
        <div id="content0" style="float:left; font-size:13px;">"Hey dude how are you doing?"</div>
        <table id="meta0" style="float:right;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="http://www.mnducksvolunteer.org/_/rsrc/1262377955090/services/Google-Contacts-32.png" width="36px" title='Google Contacts'/>
                    <img src="http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/hs455.snc4/49881_1146922913_477096_q.jpg" width="36" title="peter"/>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align:right;">
                   <div id='name' style="font-size:11px">Peter</div>
                   <div id='time' style="font-size:11px;">19:23</div>
                   <div id='date' style="font-size:11px;">23 Dec'10</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

## UPD

Here is code with divs:

```
<div id="sresults" style="position:absolute;top:120px; left:36%;">
    <div id="id0" style="width:500px;padding:5px;cursor:pointer;clear:both;">
        <div id="content0" style="float:left; font-size:13px;">"Hey dude how are you doing?"</div>
        <div id="meta0" style="float:right;">
            <img src="http://www.mnducksvolunteer.org/_/rsrc/1262377955090/services/Google-Contacts-32.png" width="36px" title='Google Contacts' style="float: left;"/>
            <img src="http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/hs455.snc4/49881_1146922913_477096_q.jpg" width="36" title="peter" style="float: left;"/>
            <div style="text-align:right; float:right">
                   <div id='name' style="font-size:11px">Peter</div>
                   <div id='time' style="font-size:11px;">19:23</div>
                   <div id='date' style="font-size:11px;">23 Dec'10</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's ugly. tables should not be used to solve layout problems.

Comment: why not? If layout is table you should use table. Thats what I think.

Comment: @RAMe0 The data is not inherently a table. He just wants it to display looking like a table now.